# What is the name of the widget inside DatePicker? How can I customize it from ThemeData?

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, themedata

I'm customizing the `DatePicker` I'm using, and I'm stuck at the widget in the highlighted area. I can't figure out which widget it is, and therefore, I'm unable to change the text to white color from `ThemeData`. How can I achieve this?

[image: DatePicker Image]

I've tried several properties, but I couldn't find the ones that stand out. The code I want to write as an example is as follows:

```
  static final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
    textSelectionTheme: const TextSelectionThemeData(
      cursorColor: AppColors.whiteColor,
      selectionColor: AppColors.scaffoldColor,
      selectionHandleColor: AppColors.activeColor,
    ),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: AppColors.scaffoldColor,
    useMaterial3: true,
    appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.scaffoldColor,
      elevation: 0,
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: AppColors.whiteColor),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBarTheme: const BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.scaffoldColor,
      elevation: 0,
      selectedItemColor: AppColors.activeColor,
      unselectedItemColor: AppColors.inactiveColor,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
    ),
  );
```

Comment: One option is to delve into this yourself.  The source code for every bit of this, down to the pixel level, is available from a few clicks in your IDE.  If you're curious about colors or fonts, you can generally just drill down and find out.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I felt the need to ask because I progressed through ThemeData and tried out the prominent properties. However, you're right thank you 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text color on the mode toggle button is controlled by the `onSurface` color from `ColorScheme`. You can modify it for the date picker like this:

```dart
showDialog<DateTime>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: Theme.of(context)
            .colorScheme
            .copyWith(onSurface: Colors.white),
      ),
      child: DatePickerDialog(
        firstDate: DateTime(2023),
        lastDate: DateTime(2025),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

If you previously used `showDatePicker`, you can move most of its parameters to the `DatePickerDialog` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The DatePicker can not be customised directly through ThemeData, but the text inside the DatePicker Header can be customised to an extent.

- [dialogBackgroundColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/dialogBackgroundColor.html) can be used to change the background color
  of the dialog where the DatePicker appears
- [ColorScheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme/ColorScheme.html) can be used since you have useMaterial3 set to true. Setting the onPrimary should affect the header text in the DatePicker.
- [headLineMedium](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme/headline4.html) or headLine4 is often used to style the date range displayed at the top of the date picker.

If these options do not work try using a custom date picker, like [Flutter Date Range Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker) or [Some Calender](https://pub.dev/packages/some_calendar).

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Actually we can customize directly our datePicker in ThemeData. It goes like this way and thank you for the answer 
```datePickerTheme: DatePickerThemeData(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.scaffoldColor,
      elevation: 5,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(20),
        ),
      ),
...
```